# Insert Japanese String in UTF-8 MySQL database and BoneCP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem to insert Japanese characters with my Java application in MySQL.
If I insert this string "今日は", I get this "???".

My table and it's fields uses UTF-8.
I don't think that the table structure is involved, because while I insert the same string from PHP, it works.

```
CREATE TABLE `pool` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `message` varchar(160) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I'm connecting to the databose with the lib "BoneCPConfig" who manage for me a pool of connexion :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
props.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");

BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig(props);
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + MYSQL_HOST_NAME + "/" + MYSQL_BASE_NAME);
config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(MIN_CONNEXION_PER_PARTITION); 
config.setPartitionCount(PARTITION_COUNT); 
config.setUsername(MYSQL_LOGIN);
config.setPassword(MYSQL_PASSWORD);
```

I do my insert like this :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO pool (message) VALUES(?) ";

PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
insertStatement.setString(1, "今日は");
insertStatement.execute();
```

I think my problem is in the connexion configuration, but I don't see what to do :-/
Have you an idea ?

---

## Edit :

problem solved, see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the lib BoneCP who don't use the property passed in parameters...
I it by replacing :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
props.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");

BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig(props);
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + MYSQL_HOST_NAME + "/" + MYSQL_BASE_NAME);
```

with :

```
BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + MYSQL_HOST_NAME + "/" + MYSQL_BASE_NAME + "?user=" + MYSQL_LOGIN + "&password=" + MYSQL_PASSWORD + "&characterEncoding=utf-8");
```

Comment: Working perfectly